# Problem compiling simple function template

Tags: c++

I'm trying to compile a simple function template however am running into compilation errors.  Does anyone know whats wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template<class T> void f1(vector<T>& arg)
{
    for (vector<T>::iterator p = arg.begin();
     p != arg.end();
     ++p)
    cout << *p << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compilation errors:

```
g++ -pedantic -Wall test102.cc && ./a.out
test102.cc: In function ‘void f1(std::vector<T>&)’:
test102.cc:7:10: error: need ‘typename’ before ‘std::vector<T>::iterator’ because ‘std::vector<T>’ is a dependent scope
     for (std::vector<T>::iterator p = arg.begin();
          ^~~
test102.cc:7:34: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘p’
     for (std::vector<T>::iterator p = arg.begin();
                                  ^~
                                  ;
test102.cc:8:3: error: ‘p’ was not declared in this scope
   p != arg.end();
   ^
```

UPDATE:
I found the error, I copied from Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed. Page 163 and it's errata `s/for (vector/for (typename vector/`.  Does anyone know why typename is required?

Comment: The error message is telling you exactly what to do. Add `typename`.

Comment: Fixed.  Why is it necessary?